# Mozilla rejected my add on (using cfx, told to use jpm)

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla

I was trying to sign my add on and after review it has been rejected with the following message
Due to breaking changes in Firefox 44, add-ons packed with the 'cfx' tool won't work any longer. To make your add-on compatible again, please use the ['jpm' tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm). You can find steps to migrate from 'cfx' to 'jpm' at "[cfx to jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx_to_jpm)". Specifically, the bootstrap.js you are using is from cfx times, please update it to the latest version.

Any idea how to update bootstrap to npm?

Comment: Which part of "please use the '[jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm)' tool" and the [cfx to jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx_to_jpm) page did you not understand?  Did you read those pages? Did you switch to using jpm and re-submit your add-on?

Comment: I already using jpm when create my xpi file the part that i didn't understand is how to update while i saw the links but i didn't understand the different from the code i had specially in bootstrapped where the one i used is the one that almost all add ons is using! so my point how to update and guarantee that i updated correctly, i am beginner with this thing so any help will be appreciated